# How to initialize a form with the values given by the user after it has failed to post?

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that in the case of it failing to post to the server, I would like the user to be brought back to the form with the data still there. Right now I have it set up where I go from the form to the php file which takes care of submitting the content to the database and will redirect back to the form after a few seconds. But if there is a failure I would like to make sure the end user doesn't have to reenter all the information.

Comment: Is the form on separate page as of php file that is processing it? Is page with form a php page?

Comment: How would it fail to post? Misvalidation? Network failure? What/

Comment: They are separate pages, and the form is on an html page.

Comment: You need to post you HTML markup and the relevant PHP code, to allow an accurate answer! Otherwise, you will get alot of guesses!

Comment: @Evo510 First thing you need to do for this to work is make form also a php page then follow any of the answers you'll find below.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet, in the event that form data fails to post, is to write it to a session variable first. The logic would go as follows:

1. Enter form data
2. Set session variables with form values
3. Post data to database, clear session variables if successful
4. Redirect back to form if post failed, populate fields with session variable data

Answer (score 0):

When a user submits a form that will fail validation, just rebuild the HTML of the form with the values you got in POST or GET and send it back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to have the form post to itself and do whatever error checking you need to do. If it passes validation then you can do whatever else you need to do (insert it in a database, send an email, forward to a thank you page, etc.) However if it fails, it will generate the form again and to populate the fields, you can use the $_POST, $_GET, or $_REQUEST variables (depending on your form's method) to re-populate the fields.

For example, if you had a name field like `<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />` you could modify that to be:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php echo $_POST['fname']?>" />
```

This will populate the field with whatever data the user entered. Select menus, checkboxes, and radio buttons can also be re-populated using the form data previously entered, and the code is just slightly more complex.